# how to add an existing bot to custom microsoft app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

how to add "now virtual agent"(service now bot in microsoft teams) to custom microsoft team. Do I need to register the "now virtual agent" in azure?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate a Virtual agent Bot in Teams App, you need to publish your bot and need to add Microsoft Teams channel to [make the Bot reachable to Teams Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/add-power-virtual-agents-bot-to-teams#make-your-chatbot-reachable-in-teams-in-the-power-virtual-agents-portal). Once the Team channel is successfully added you will get an App ID. Now you can [create an App Package for Teams using App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/add-power-virtual-agents-bot-to-teams#add-your-bot-to-teams-using-app-studio), You need to put the App Id for your Bot in bot Configuration. Look at [Add Chat bot to Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-app-certification/teams/servicenow-now-virtual-agent?pivots=general) documentation

Comment: Hi Trinetra, I am not refering to power virtual agent bot. We have a "Now virtual agent" bot in microsoft teams under app category. I need add this bot to a custom teams app which i have created.Where can i find the App ID of the inbuilt bot? or if i have to register the inbuilt bot where am i supposed to register as i no option to select existing bot in bot registration nor we app nor Power virtual agent.

Comment: Can you check this documentation which specify id for your [Now Virtual Agent Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-app-certification/teams/servicenow-now-virtual-agent?pivots=general)?

Comment: I was able to connect with the specified ID when I put in my App Studio package Bot configuration

Comment: ok i will try configuring the bot again and see. And i also see that the url(sharepoint url) specified in my teams tab opens in a new window of the browser. Any setting which i have to modify to make the app sure the url in opened in teams app.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Hi Trinetra, I was able to add bot in my app. But unable to access the url specified in personal tab it say connection refused. I read few documents and understood that the issue may be because of iframe. I am not sure how to make "www.google.com" iframeable as i am using no code teams app. If you can help on this it will be great.

Comment: That should be done by code else it will throw refused to connect error try with any URL which is an iframe